# EGL/OpenGLES glGenFramebuffers not working with Native Android Project in VS 2019

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, visual-studio-2019, egl

I have been trying to render to texture with EGL, but `glGenFramebuffers` is not giving me a valid frame buffer object.

`glGetError()` returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

The project template I'm using is from this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cross-platform/build-an-opengl-es-application-on-android-and-ios?view=vs-2019

I tried calling `glGenFramebuffers` in various locations in case the OpenGL ES API wasn't fully initialized.  Then I tried creating a brand new Native Android project with Visual Studio 2019 and calling `glGenFramebuffers' with the same result.

Here is my initialization for my NativeActivity.  You can see at the bottom I am creating the frame buffer.  It always gives me 0.  There are no other threads.  This is from a fresh Native Activity project and I moved most of the setup to a single `init()`.

```
void init()
{
    const EGLint attribs[] =
    {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLConfig pConfig;
    EGLint nFormat;
    EGLint nNumConfigs;
    m_pDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    eglInitialize(m_pDisplay, 0, 0));
    eglChooseConfig(m_pDisplay, attribs, &pConfig, 1, &nNumConfigs);
    eglGetConfigAttrib(m_pDisplay, pConfig, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &nFormat);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(m_pApp->window, 0, 0, nFormat);

    m_pSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(m_pDisplay, pConfig, m_pApp->window, nullptr);
    m_pContext = eglCreateContext(m_pDisplay, pConfig, nullptr, nullptr);
    eglMakeCurrent(m_pDisplay, m_pSurface, m_pSurface, m_pContext);

    eglQuerySurface(m_pDisplay, m_pSurface, EGL_WIDTH, &m_nWidth);
    eglQuerySurface(m_pDisplay, m_pSurface, EGL_HEIGHT, &m_nHeight);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    GLuint nFrameBuffer = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &nFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, nFrameBuffer);
}
```

An easy way to reproduce the issue yourself is to create a new OpenGLES Native Application project and in the NativeActivity `engine_init_display()`.  Try to create a frame buffer at the very bottom of `engine_init_display()`, after the call to `Cube_setupGL()`.

Comment: Please post a complete example of how you are setting this up. The odds are that the problem is related to your context setup (e.g. calling this from a different thread to the one which has the graphics context bound), but it's impossible to tell from what little you've posted.

Comment: I had planned on eventually loading textures on a separate thread.  So is that not possible?  Just so we're clear, there's no multi-threading on my original post.

Comment: glGetError() returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION when I call glGenFramebuffers().  I've seen other posts online about that, but nothing that helped me in this case.